# VBA Change color of cell using an Address variable

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I am trying to change the color of group of cells, but the range of the group will vary according to the value within a couple of other cells. I have already learned how to do this varying range for a formula. That code looks like this:

```
Dim T1Address As String

c1 = Sheets(2).Range("AQ3").Value
t1 = Sheets(2).Range("AR3").Value

T1Address = Cells(8, c1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, _
                                             ColumnAbsolute:=False) & ":" & Cells(8, t1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, _
                                             ColumnAbsolute:=False)

Range("AT3").Formula = "=COUNTA('" & Worksheets(1).Name & "'!" & T1Address & ")"
```

That for multiple T1Address, c1, t1, etc. (c2, c3, ..., cn). The thing is now I need to change the color of the cells that compose the range of that formula, for example if the resulting formula is =COUNTA(A3:B4) I need to change the color of A3:B4 for a specific RGB color. I have the RGB color for each range as the values of cells in a column. I tried to emulate this:

```
Range("A1:A6").Interior.Color = RGB(127,187,199)
```

Doing this:

```
Dim Color1 As String
Color1 = Sheets(2).Range("D50").Value 'The value of D50 is RGB(217, 225, 242)
Range("T1Address").Interior.Color = Color1
```

It tells me that there is an error 1004. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: change `Dim Color1 As String` to `Dim Color1 As Long`, as `RGB` return a `Long` value

Comment: You have used a string literal of `"T1Address"` as the range name, rather than the value of the variable `T1Address`.  You need to use `Range(T1Address).Interior.Color = Color1`.